# Unique ID for sftp user in log

Tags: debian, logging, sftp

I am logging SFTP behaviour in /var/log/auth.log. Output looks like this

```
May 27 05:58:16 test-server sshd[20044]: User child is on pid 20049
May 27 05:58:16 test-server sshd[20049]: subsystem request for sftp by user test-user
May 27 05:58:16 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: session opened for local user test-user from [192.168.1.1]
May 27 05:58:16 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: received client version 3
May 27 05:58:16 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: realpath "."
May 27 05:58:21 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: opendir "/home/test-user/"
May 27 05:58:21 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: closedir "/home/test-user/"
May 27 05:58:21 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: lstat name "/home/test-user/upload"
May 27 05:58:21 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: realpath "/home/test-user/upload/"
May 27 05:58:21 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: stat name "/home/test-user/upload"
May 27 05:58:24 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: open "/home/test-user/upload/test-file.pdf" flags WRITE,CREATE,TRUNCATE mode 0664
May 27 05:58:25 test-server internal-sftp[20050]: close "/home/test-user/upload/test-file.pdf" bytes read 0 written 1282941
```

But, the ID changes always for new session. Is there possibility to have same ID for every session for every single user? For example user "child" will have for all his sessions ID `20050`.

I am looking for this or similar solution so I can parse this to my system and have records about user behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a session ID. It's the process ID of the process that handles the connection. This ID is given by the Linux kernel when a process starts. It's not possible that this ID stays the same.

Comment: Thank you for information, and is possible to change logging of SSH so there will be some unique indentificator for sessions?

Comment: Not that I know of.